# Handle huge data imported from facebook

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, bigdata, batch-processing, job-scheduling

I'm currently create a program that imports all groups and feeds from Facebook which the user wants.
I used to use the Graph API with OAuth and this works very well.

But I came to the point that I realized that one request can't handle the import of 1000 groups plus the feeds.

So I'm looking for a solution that imports this data in the background (like a cron job) into a database.

Requirements

- Runs in background
- Runs under Linux
- Restful

Questions

- What's you experience about that?
- Would hadoop the right solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use neo4j.
Neo4j is a graph database, reliable and fast for managing and querying highly connected data

http://www.neo4j.org/

1) Decide structure of nodes, relationships, and there properties and accordingly
You need to create API that will get data from facebook and store it in Neo4j.

I have used neo4j in 3 big projects, and it is best for graph data.

2) Create a cron jon that will get data from facebook and store into the neo4j.

I think implementing mysql for graph database is not a good idea. for large data neo4j is the good option.

Comment: Can you give some figures in terms of "big" and "best"? How many records results into how much occupied space results into which response time? +How much RAM did you have?

Comment: For use of maintaining graph data Neo4j is best.

Here is the comparison between neo4j with RDBMS DB.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/mysql-vs-neo4j-large-scale

Comment: As per René Pickhardt research neo4j is 377 time faster than mysql.
http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/time-lines-and-news-streams-neo4j-is-377-times-faster-than-mysql/

Comment: I could question every aspect of René Pickhard's test. Just some examples: which indexes did he have for the mysql tables? How was his memory settings for either setup? Did he not rather test bandwidth with that high amount of data? Again these are just examples

Comment: For the dzone.com article I liked first the better presentation of the setup. But after the second look I stated, that the test was about a very specific traversal scenario. Also as one of its comment says there are still things of the setup unclear. Does this test fit to one of the use cases of this question?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly you designed the appropriate solution yourself already. So in fact you need following components:

- a relational database, since you want to request data in a structured, quick way

  -> from experiences I would pressure the fact to have a fully normalized data model (in your case with tables users, groups, users2groups), also have 4-Byte surrogate keys over larger keys from facebook (for back referencing you can store their keys as attributes, but internal relations are more efficient on surrogate keys)

  -> establish indexes based on hashes rather than strings (eg. crc32(lower(STRING))) - an example select would than be this: select somethinguseful from users where name=SEARCHSTRING and hash=crc32(lower(SEARCHSTRING))

  -> never,ever establish unique columns based on strings with length > 8 Byte; unique bulk inserts can be done based on hashes+string checking via insert...select

  -> once you got that settled you could also look into sparse matrices (see wikipedia) and bitmaps to get your users2groups optimized (however I have learned that this is an extra that should not hinder you to come up with a first version soon)
- a cron job that is run periodically

  -> ideally along the caps, facebook is giving you (so if they rule you to not request more often than once per second, stick to that - not more, but also try to come as close as possible to the cap) -> invest some time in getting the management of this settled, if different types of requests need to be fired (request for user records <> requests for group records, but maybe hit by the same cap)

  -> most of the optimization can only be done with development - so if I were you I would stick to any high level programming language that does not bother to much with var type juggling and that also comes along with a broad support for associative arrays such as PHP and I would programm that thing myself

  -> I made good experiences with setting up the cron job as web page with deactivated output buffering (for php look at ob_end_flush(void)) - easy to test and the cron job can be triggered via curl; if you channel status outputs via an own function (eg with time stamps) this could then also become flexible to either run viw browser or via command line -> which means efficient testing + efficient production running
- your user ui, which only requests your database and never, ever, never the external system api
- lots of memory, to keep your performance high (optimal: all your data+index data fits into database memory/cache dedicated to the database)

  -> if you use mysql as database you should look into innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0, and innodb_buffer_pool_size (just google, if interested)

Hadoop is a file system layer - it could help you with availability. However I would put this into the category of "sparse matrix", which is nothing that stops you from coming up with a solution. From my experience availability is not a primary constraint in data exposure projects.

-------------------------- UPDATE -------------------

I like neo4j from the other answer. So I wondered what I can learn for my future projects. My experiences with mysql is that RAM is usually the biggest constraint. So increasing your RAM to be able to load the full database can gain you performance improvements by a factor of 2-1000 - depending on from where you are coming from. Everything else such as index improvements and structure somehow follows. So if I would need to make up a performance prioritization list, it would be something like this:

1. MYSQL + enough RAM dedicated to the database to load all data
2. NEO4J + enough RAM dedicated to the database to load all data

I would still prefer MYSQL. It stores records efficiently, but needs to run joins for deriving relations (which neo4j does not require to that extend). Join-costs are usually low with the right indexes and according to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-caches.html neo4j does need to add extra management data to the property separation. For big data projects those management data sums up and in full load to memory set ups requires you buy more memory. Performance wise these both options are ultimate. Further, much further down the line you would find this:

1. NEO4J + not enough RAM dedicated to the database to load all data
2. MYSQL + not enough RAM dedicated to the database to load all data

In worst case MYSQL will even put indexes to disk (at least partly), which can result in massive read delay. In comparison with NEO4J you could perform a ' direct jump from node to node' exercise, which should - at least in theory - be faster.